# Rendering to BufferedImage with JOGL

Tags: java, opengl

I am looking for a way to use the [JOGL library](https://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) to capture the output of a shader in a BufferedImage. Do I need to create a frame buffer?

(Also, I would like to have the shader use another BufferedImage as input, so I would have to upload that as a texture I assume. This seems like the easier part though.)

Comment: 1)Create an framebuffer and an full screen quad 2)render your scene into that frame buffer 3)read the rgb pixels of your framebuffer texture using glGetPixels and store that into an buffered image. So yes you create an frame buffer

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to create a frame buffer?

There is always a framebuffer, the default framebuffer (0). You can get the pixels of the color plane of the currently bound framebuffer (`GL_FRAMEBUFFER`/`GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER`) with [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml).

> Also, I would like to have the shader use another BufferedImage as input ...

You can generate a named framebuffer and attach a texture to its color plane. So you can render directly into this texture. Finally, you can use this texture in another shader stage. (Texture data  can be read with [`glGetTexImage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml)).

You can also use a [Pixel Buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object) to copy the pixels from the framebuffer to texture image. Bind a buffer to the `GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER` target and use `glReadPixels` to copy the pixel into the buffer. Bind the buffer to the `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER` target and write the data into the texture image with `glTexImage2D`.